# How to set location or similar property in System.Windows.Controls.TextBox C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am making a `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`.  I need it to be a `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`, not a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`, because a method needs it for SpellCheck.  I have figured out, or looked up most of the other properties for this control, but I can not find this, either on Google, Stack Overflow, or Microsoft.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
this.tbSearch.Name = "tbSearch";
//this.tbSearch.LOCATION    //this needs to be replaced
this.tbSearch.Width = 313;
this.tbSearch.Height = 20;
this.tbSearch.TabIndex = 2;
this.tbSearch.TextChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventHandler(this.tbSearch_TextChanged);
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**

I am using WinForms.

Comment: There are addons to give a `Forms.Textbox` a spell-check property. That might be easier.

Comment: `System.Windows.Controls` classes are WPF controls.  You can't place a WPF control directly in a WinForm form.  You need to "host" it with a [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control.

Comment: @krillgar do you have any links?  Thanks!

Comment: @DStanley how do you use that?  Any links?  Thanks

Comment: @cullub Here's a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: [NHunspell](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33658/NHunspell-Hunspell-for-the-NET-platform) is the one that I have used in the past. It was rather easy to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`Margin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin(v=vs.110).aspx) property, a [`System.Windows.Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness(v=vs.110).aspx) object:

```
this.tbSearch.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

**Update**

Totally seems to work in WPF.

CS:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.tbSearch.Margin = new Thickness(this.tbSearch.Margin.Left - 10,
    this.tbSearch.Margin.Top - 10,
    this.tbSearch.Margin.Right,
    this.tbSearch.Margin.Bottom);
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
<TextBox Name="tbSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="198,159,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

WinForms with ElementHost

- http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms
- https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/

Comment: That sets a sort of border; I want something that sets the position of the control in relation to the form, or it's parent object.  Thanks Anyways!

Comment: Is the Form you're adding to a System.Windows.Form? I was assuming a WPF System.Windows.Window or Control (for which it totally works, see update)

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding this to a Form? If so, all controls on a form support setting of .Top and .Left to position the element relative to the top-left corner of the former.

Comment: I am adding this to a form, however, this is a `System.Windows.Control` object, not `System.Windows.Forms`.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're adding a WPF object (System.Windows.Control.Textbox is in the PresentationFramework assembly) to a WinForm? Can you show where you're adding it to the form's control collection?